# Why does Wubi give an "installation size" of 18 GB?

Tags: installation, partitioning, wubi

When I run Wubi, that is, the Windows installer for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, I'm given a pull-down menu in the download dialog-box. It offers, pre-set, an *Installation Size* of 18 GB, although one can pull down the menu and choose, it seems, anywhere from 5 GB to 30 GB. Which size should I choose?

And why isn't this feature mentioned in the download instructions that are linked to from the download page? I must admit, I am miffed by this apparent omission.

Comment: don't use wubi,it had lot of bugs.

Comment: Wubi Is old and outdated! Use the regular installation!

Answer (score 1):

WUBI is an abandoned project and is not compatible with [UEFI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI). It is also just for try ubuntu, not really for a long term usage, if you want to use Ubuntu on a long term i recomend you to make a partition for it.

Answer (score 1):

Wubi makes a file that acts like a drive when you boot ubuntu.
So instead of making a new partition to put your os on , you choose the size of your "drive" in the "Installation Size" dropdown menu!

Comment: Thank you! May I ask if I should keep it at 18 GB? (I've got a small laptop--1 GB RAM, Windows 7 Starter (32 bit)--it's an Acer Aspire One "netbook." There's about 195 GB on the hard drive.)